# How to use Primefaces SelectOneRadio's Custom Layout on Dynamic List

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Primefaces provides option of customizing the Layout of `p:selectOneRadio` which is a good over the treditonal JSF `h:selectOneRadio` which generates `<table>`.

But everywhere I see using this Custom Layout on fixed/static Radio buttons even in Primefaces [Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneRadio.jsf). where they used over:

```
 <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" value="#{formBean.option}" layout="custom">  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
    </p:selectOneRadio>
```

I want use this custom Layout on `f:selectItems` which iterates over a `ArrayList`.
like,

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" value="#{formBean.option}" layout="custom">  
      <f:selectItems value="#{formBean.mySelectItemList}"/> 
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

How To do that? or any other alternatives?

*Using: JSF 2.1.13 and Primefaces 3.5*

Answer (score 2):

A convenient way to solve it would be to use JSTL `c:forEach` with `f:selectItems` just the way you wrote it in your question. You could add the following to define the layout:

```
<c:forEach items="#{formBean.mySelectItemList}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <p:radioButton id="customRadioButton" for="customRadio" itemIndex="#{loop.index}" />
    <!-- whatever custom layout you prefer here -->
    <p:inputText />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -4):

In my application I have a such implementation I am sharing the code

```
 <p:selectOneRadio value="#{insertbean.lagCalid}" layout="pageDirection">
<f:selectItems value="#{insertbean.calendars}" var="cal" itemLabel="#{cal.calendarName}" itemValue="#{cal.calrowid}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

lagcalid has getter setter; calendars is of type `List<Calendar>`, Calendar is my own model class. calendars has getter method in which it is populated with data. pageDirection has the same custom like view as primefaces showcase.

Comment: This is not I want. I know how to use the POJO's in `f:selectItems` and I'm not asking for `layout="pageDirection"`. I want to use `layout="custom"` when there are `f:selectItems` and put Dropdown and other components along with radio button. See the Primefaces Link that I provided in Question.

Comment: Please pay attention to the question. @KishorP needs custom layout.